# > Task :invertase_react-native-apple-authentication:parseDebugLibraryResources FAILED

Tags: java, react-native, gradle

**I have a problem when im starting a proj in Android studio using Yarn mb someone had the same problem **
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1440 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

> Configure project :app
> Error 'Plugin-Version' of 'unspecified' for 'com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin@76a4096' is not a valid version number
> OneSignal Warning: Could not get AGP plugin version

> Task :invertase_react-native-apple-authentication:parseDebugLibraryResources FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
8 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 6 up-to-date

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':invertase_react-native-apple-authentication:parseDebugLibraryResources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':invertase_react-native-apple-authentication:androidApis'.
> Failed to transform android.jar to match attributes {artifactType=android-platform-attr, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for PlatformAttrTransform: /Users/admin/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-29/android.jar.
> > /Users/admin/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-29/android.jar (No such file or directory)

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.

Answer (score 14):

I don't know if this applies to your exact situation, but I had a similar error and solved it by explicity specifying the Kotlin version in the buildscript block in build.gradle, like this:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        ndkVersion = "22.1.7171670"
        kotlinVersion = "1.5.30"
        androidXAnnotation = "1.1.0"
        androidXBrowser = "1.0.0"
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "17.+"
    }

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'
    }
}
```

I was able to find the Kotlin version in Android Studio under Preferences -> Plugins.

Comment: Yeah ! I am developing with react-native and had this error :

`execution failed for task ':app:compiledebugjavawithjavac' react-native`

And this solution worked for me

Comment: Finding the right kotlin version helps